# Foreign key constraint fails when trying to add custom product attribute option

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, attribute-options

I added a product attribute called `size` from admin with the same settings as `color` attribute. Now when i programmatically try to add an option to this attribute I get a MySQL error:

```
Cannot save attribute SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eav_attribute_option_value`, CONSTRAINT `EAV_ATTR_OPT_VAL_OPT_ID_EAV_ATTR_OPT_OPT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`option_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_option` (`option_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_option_value` (`option_id`, `store_id`, `value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Code to add option:

```
/* \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterfaceFactory $optionFactory */
$option = $this->optionFactory->create();
$option->setLabel('120cm')->setValue('120cm')->setSortOrder(0);

/* \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface $optionManagement */
$this->optionManagement->add(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'size', $option);
```

When I try to add attribute option `color` with the same code as above, everything works fine and option is added.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer after posting this question. I am going to post the answer here for future reference or anyone with the same problem.

Basically, if you set option value with `$option->setValue($value)` then option_id will obtain the value from `$option->getValue()` intcast. And in case of the value being `'120mm'` for example, the result will be `120`. That's why it fails.

So, the solution is to not do `$option->setValue($value)`

The problem and answer is explained in more detail [here](https://dev98.de/2016/12/21/how-to-create-attribute-options-in-magento2/)

Comment: This link will help any others facing this problem. Basically wrapping the array key value in qoutes will fix the error. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5715